# 404 error using Valence GET classlist

Tags: php, http-status-code-404, valence

I'm trying to retrieve a classlist using the PHP Valence API, and I keep getting the 404 error:

`string(39) "Unknown error occured (HTTP status 404)"`

Not sure what is causing this error as I've gotten good results when using the same call in the API test tool.

`/d2l/api/le/1.0/123456/classlist/`

Here is the code:

```
<?php
require_once "config.php";

require_once $config['libpath'] . "/D2LAppContextFactory.php";
require_once $config['libpath'] . "/DoValenceRequest.php";

$authContextFactory = new D2LAppContextFactory();
$authContext = $authContextFactory->createSecurityContext($config['appId'],$config['appKey']);
$hostSpec = new D2LHostSpec($config['host'],$config['port'],$config['scheme']);
$opContext = $authContext->createElevatedContextFromHostSpec($hostSpec,$config['elevated_username'],$config['ele$
$response = doValenceRequest($opContext,'GET','/d2l/api/le/1.0/123456/classlist');
var_dump($response);exit;
?>
```

123456 = the OrgUnitId

Why am I getting a 404 error?
Any help would be much appreciated!

-- Valence Newbie

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would recommend that you change the API version that you are using. Version 1.0 is now obsolete. Here is a link explaining Valence versioning:

http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/about.html#current-release-changes

My second thought is that is the OrgUnitId actually 123456? Or is that the OrgUnitCode?

Comment: 123456 was the OrgUnitId. I changed the version and it worked! Thanks!